# Webview javascript not executing if there is some error in the html page

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am using webview in my app for payment. Now I have come across a scenario in which there is some error in the html content due to which a javascript in that page is unable to execute. While the same javascript is executing in desktop browser. What can be the issue? I have enabled javascript in my webview but still such a thing is happening

I have normal code for webview settings.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Neither I can open that url due to lack of parameters

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: you can print log, js call native method

Comment: I have normal code for webview settings. Neither I can open that url due to lack of parameters

Comment: @LingYFH Didnt get you

Comment: @mohanmishra click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) ,     webpage call native method to print debug log.

Comment: @mohanmishra, can you paste console log here, for devices with OS 4.4 and above they will be printed in logcat with tag as chromiuim , for older devices you can find them with tag console. Also I will suggest to use chrome inspect tool to debug the same